# 176VDC - 10A power supply

Tags: power-supply

This is what is required by my motor: 176VDC and 6A (10A for security)
I think this will be complicated to find one on second hand market.
My house is powered with 230VAC single phase and 380V 3-phase
Maybe I should built it from scratch? 
What are my options and what is your advice?

1. build my own transformer and add a rectifier bridge ?
2. Other one maybe easier?

Comment: The answer would depend on your own knowledge/skills. If you know what you're doing, go ahead and make your own rectifier. But i would definitely not "build my own transformer", get a commercial one. First of all, check with the motor manufacturer, they could have an off-shelf rectifier.

Comment: I don't have huge knowlede but tis is also the opportunity to learn.
This is a old Siemens motor, production stopped in 2009. I really doubt Siemens will supply a power supply for a hobbyist

Comment: Well, I would advise against learning by messing with mains and trying to supply up to 176V x 10A. Anything you build, without proper safeguards, could be hazardous. If you wish to learn, start with lower power ratings.

Comment: I'm sorry but messing around with a 180VDC 10A DIY PSU isn't a very good opportunity to learn. This is one of the cases were this is likely valid: "If you have to ask, you probably shouldn't be doing this".

Comment: This is also why I was asking if their was other way to proceed

Comment: “Easiest” could be to find a 230:230 transformer and unwind a few turns off the secondary. That and a suitable bridge rectifier and you should be good. You should be able to cheat and skip the top wave rectification. Depending on the peak voltage capability of the isolation in the motor, a simple thyristor DC motor speed controller straight on 230 Vac and set it to 170 Vdc output should work too.

Comment: A builder's 110V (AC) isolating transformer (usually supplied in a yellow plastic enclosure) is probably the easiest way. Rectify and smooth that and it'll be reasonably close to the specified voltage.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use a "power supply" for a 176V, 6A DC motor. Such a motor is intended to be powered by some type of electronic speed control (ESC) that controls both the voltage and current so that the motor does not draw too much current when starting and accelerating. It is likely that the motor requires both a variable voltage for the armature and a fixed voltage for the field. To get the best advice on ECS requirements, you should post the complete data listed on the motor's rating plate. It is likely that an appropriate ESC could be supplied directly from 230V AC.